# Принцип композиции

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В проекте должен быть использован принцип композиции для работы с формами на страницах
Может кто-то объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

Композиция - это когда объект одного класса находится внутри объекта другого класса.
Например: у нас есть класс **Автомобиль** и класс **Двигатель**. Двигатель находится внутри класса Автомобиль в виде поля. И получается, что при удалении объекта Автомобиль будет удаляться объект Двигатель.

```
 public class Engine
{ }
 
public class Car
{
    Engine engine;
    public Car()
    {
        engine = new Engine();
    }
}
```

То есть при композиции один объект находится как бы **внутри** другого и зависит от него

Comment: В композиции класс, известный как составной, содержит объект другого класса, известный как компонент. 

Композиция позволяет составным классам повторно использовать реализацию компонентов, которые она содержит. Составнойой класс не наследует интерфейс класса компонента, но может использовать его реализацию.

Композиционные отношения между двумя классами считаются слабосвязанными. Это означает, что изменения в классе компонентов редко влияют на составной класс, а изменения в составном классе никогда не влияют на класс компонентов.

Это обеспечивает лучшую адаптируемость к изменениям. КАК?

Comment: Видимо тогда имеется ввиду, что в классе формы должны находиться объекты компонентов (кнопок, текстовых полей и т д.) Либо я не до конца понимаю

Comment: @VyacheslavH, условно - если у автомобиля поменять двигатель на другой (в воображаемой вселенной), она в идеале будет продолжать ездить, ну и замена магнитолы никак не влияет на двигатель ("Это означает, что изменения в классе компонентов редко влияют на составной класс, а изменения в составном классе никогда не влияют на класс компонентов"). Если бы, например, машина наследовалась от двигателя, замена двигателя на другой потребовала бы глобальной переделки машины - это была бы сильная связанность)